# Why is usb mouse frozen after boot-up and running Vivaldi?

Tags: usb, mouse

I am running 22.04 on a Dell Latitude 7620 Plus with a dual boot Windows 11. All the latest device updates have been installed under W11 which I assume have an impact on how Ubuntu handles some devices.

The issue occurs randomly, generally after a reboot or after suspend, where running Vivaldi and Zoom plus some other mouse driven applications causes the Logitech M185 mouse pointer to freeze. The quick way to correct the issue is remove the usb widget, wait 10 sec and reinsert. After the freeze the built-in mouse pad still works. When mouse freeze happens after running Zoom the built-in camera is no longer available though most times it's label is still in the drop-down menu.

Can anyone shed any light on the issue?

**Solved...**
There were 2 Nvidia updates just released by Dell. Once installed the problem has gone away!